# Which Amazon web services can be used with Delphi 'out of the box'?

Tags: delphi, soap, delphi-2009, amazon-web-services

The feature matrix for Delphi says: 'Added in 2007! SOAP features updated to support Amazon, eBay, MapPoint, and more'.

I was able to build a working client, without special workarounds for the Amazon Simple Queue Service. With Amazon SimpleDB, I ran out of luck (but not because of Delphi, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842948)).

Which Amazon web services have you sucessfully tested or used with Delphi 2007 (or 2009)?

Was it necessary to use special workarounds to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using [n software Amazon Integrator](http://www.nsoftware.com/ibiz/amazon/) in my current project for a client. It's not cheap, but supports most of Amazon's services (Simple Storage Service (S3), Simple Queue Service (SQS), SimpleDB, Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2), and E-Commerce Service (AWS)). It's not "out of the box" solution, but with a help of a third party component.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "out of the box". With AWS, you can make either SOAP or REST calls which means you should be able to use almost any language you like. If you wanted to use a helper library, I have not heard of any for Delphi.

For the reference, you can check out this for SimpleDB:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/APIRequests.html

Comment: Delphi does not support SOAP 1.2 (SOAP 1.1 seems to be deprecated for Amazon Web Services), Delphi has no built-in support for WS-Security, and the SimpleDB WSDL is incomplete and thus usable for a Delphi SOAP client. Actually I am looking for success stories :)